# I want to do vlookup or self join or mapping data to blank cell using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Checking multiple cells, skipping if blank and returning the value of the cell once it is found

e.g **this is my dataframe**

| Name | type |
| --- | --- |
| hdfc | large |
| hdfc |  |
| itc |  |
| itc | small |
| its |  |
| sai | mid |
| guru |  |
| vishal | data |
| vishal |  |

**expected output**

| Name | type |
| --- | --- |
| hdfc | large |
| hdfc | large |
| itc | small |
| itc | small |
| its | small |
| sai | mid |
| guru |  |
| vishal | data |
| vishal | data |

i tried this code

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "stock": ["hdfc", "hdfc", "itc", "itc", "its", "sai", "guru", "vishal", "vishal"],
    "type": ["large", "", "", "small", "", "mid", "", "data", ""]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Use forward fill to fill missing values in the 'type' column
df['type'] = df['type'].replace('', method='ffill')

print(df)
```

but its returning "data" value against Guru, which is not right it should be blank cuz we are performing vlookup type thing but in python. There is no value present against guru name then it should be blank rather than taking value by from up or below cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary from rows with values, then update the entire df using the dict:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {
    "stock": ["hdfc", "hdfc", "itc", "itc", "its", "sai", "guru", "vishal", "vishal"],
    "type": ["large", "", "", "small", "", "mid", "", "data", ""]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#     stock   type
# 0    hdfc  large
# 1    hdfc       
# 2     itc       
# 3     itc  small
# 4     its       
# 5     sai    mid
# 6    guru       
# 7  vishal   data
# 8  vishal       

dfcopy = df.copy()
dfcopy = dfcopy.replace("", np.nan) #Replace empty string with nan
dfcopy = dfcopy.sort_values(by=["stock","type"], na_position="last") #To be able to sort them last
dfcopy = dfcopy.drop_duplicates(subset=["stock"], keep="first") #Drop duplicate rows, keep first

filler = dict(zip(dfcopy["stock"],dfcopy["type"])) #Create a dict with all values to use for each stock
#{'guru': nan, 'hdfc': 'large', 'itc': 'small', 'its': nan, 'sai': 'mid', 'vishal': 'data'}

df["type"] = df["stock"].map(filler).fillna("") #Update stock column by dict
    stock   type
0    hdfc  large
1    hdfc  large
2     itc  small
3     itc  small
4     its       
5     sai    mid
6    guru       
7  vishal   data
8  vishal   data
```